# My login controller doesn't work. Problem with fetching username

Tags: sqlalchemy, pylons

Currently my login controller doesn't work because i can't seem to fetch the username and password.

I'm currently using something like this:

```
form_username = str(request.params.get('username'))

db_user = meta.Session.query(User).filter_by(username=form_username)
if db_user is None:
    return redirect('auth/error')
```

No matter which username is use, db_user always returns True and thus never goes to auth/error. I used the shell to play with this and i was able establish a connection with the database, so i'm not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: is db_user empty instead of the special value None?

Comment: How would i check if it's empty? If i type db_user in shell i get a "Query Object. at ...."

Comment: Maybe i'm supposed to use something else than filter_by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track; you just need to go one step further.

As you mention in the comments above, `filter_by()` returns a Query object.
You need to specify which method of the Query object you want to use to actually run the query and return some results.

In this case, I'd recommend `first()`.

```
db_user = meta.Session.query(User).filter_by(username=form_username).first()
```

[Documentation](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/05/reference/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.first) (my emphasis):

> Return the first result of this Query **or None if the result doesn’t contain any row**. This results in an execution of the underlying query.